# Pixel Poro - What do the gems / hearts do?

Tags: pixel-poro

Riot has released [Pixel Poro](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/node/16118), a minigame with pong-like mechanics to coincide with Braum's release.

On some points a red poro flys briefly across the screen, like this:
[image: Red Poro]

If you can get the white poro to pass through the red poro, you get a gem/heart:
[image: Poro Heart]

The interface looks like it accommodates 3 gems, but I can't get more than one.  Getting a single gem doesn't appear to influence the game.  What is the point of the gems?  Does something special happen if you get 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, they are not hearts; they are gems. I played a 2P game to get all 3 and was dissapointed when nothing happened at first.[image]

Then I won the game with Braum and pressed Menu and went back to 1P mode and was suprised to face off against Taric in the next battle.[image] Unfortunately if you lose you have to fight Leona again. I don't know what happens if you get all 3 gems while fighting Taric.

Comment: +1 It looks like getting 3 hearts/gems unlocks a new opponent.  Maybe a skilled / determined / lucky player could find out how many opponents there are?